# creating simple drop down menu for a form

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a simple HTML question form with drop down menu options.  After the user selects the answer choices I want them to hit submit and the form just updates the page with the answers selected.  I don't want the answers to be uploaded to a database, just simply want the answers to be displayed/page updated (eg the drop down menus are no longer active).

This is what I have:

```
<label for="InputOne">Input One</label>
<select id="InputOne">
    <option val="1">1</option>
    <option val="2">2</option>
    <option val="3">3</option>
    <option val="4">4</option>
</select>

<label for="InputTwo">Input Two</label>
<select id="InputTwo">
    <option val="1">a</option>
    <option val="2">b</option>
    <option val="3">c</option>
    <option val="4">d</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

so for instance if a person selects "2" and "c" from the drop down menu and hits submit, how do i get the page just to update so now the text displayed "Input One 2 Input Two C" without the drop down menu and submit buttons active/displayed.  thank you.

Comment: Please refer to the [ask] section in order to ask a proper question. StackOverflow is not designed for people to write code for you - have a go yourself and then if you have an issue come and ask a question.

Comment: ok sorry. i've updated my post. thank you.